# Adding Tenant in WSO2 programmatically

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to add a tenant in WSO2 programmatically using java (i.e without using the API Manager console). I tried using "RemoteTenantManagerService" in the Admin Services but it gives an error:

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault:
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error in adding tenant
>   with tenant domain: test.com

I enabled debug logs and found:

> {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.TenantManager} -  Error in adding
>   tenant with tenant domain: test.com.
>   {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.TenantManager}
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor.serialize(RealmConfigXMLProcessor.java:72)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager.addTenant(JDBCTenantManager.java:109)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.service.TenantManagerService.addTenant(TenantManagerService.java:41)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue using the service "TenantMgtAdminService" while adding tenant programatically. Tenant details can be set in "TenantInfoBean" and added as - TenantMgtAdminServiceStub.addTenant(TenantInfoBean).

Imports are:
org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.stub.TenantMgtAdminServiceStub and org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.stub.beans.xsd.TenantInfoBean.

Cheers!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try using https://localhost:9443/services/TenantMgtService?wsdl as you WSDL

Note: Before using admin services you need to set

```
<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs> in carbon.xml
```

(file located at: /repository/conf/carbon.xml

My sample soap envelop is given below,

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://services.mgt.tenant.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://beans.common.stratos.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
  <ser:registerTenantForTrustedUser>
     <ser:tenantInfoBean>
        <xsd:active>true</xsd:active>
        <xsd:admin>admin</xsd:admin>
        <xsd:adminPassword>admin</xsd:adminPassword>
        <xsd:email>channa@abc.com</xsd:email>
        <xsd:firstname>Channa</xsd:firstname>
        <xsd:lastname>E</xsd:lastname>
        <xsd:tenantDomain>abc.test.com</xsd:tenantDomain>
        <xsd:tenantId>-1</xsd:tenantId>
     </ser:tenantInfoBean>
  </ser:registerTenantForTrustedUser>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

With above I was able to successfully create a tenant

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I received the below error: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value>
         </soapenv:Code>
         <soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">wrong number of arguments</soapenv:Text>
         </soapenv:Reason>
         <soapenv:Detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Could you please share a sample soap request that you made along with wso2 carbon error logs so we can identify the root cause?
also please do mention the wso2 product and the version